# VS Code not highlighting HTML in index.php even with beautify enabled

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, php-extensions

working on a PHP project, but the HTML in my PHP is not highlighting.

I'm not sure why, but html by itself will.

When I installed beautify, per another posts recommendation, my user settings did not update. So I went to the github repo to add the configuration for beautify manually.

Here is the code snippet I added and updated in my user settings.

```
"beautify.language": {
  "js": {
    "type": ["javascript", "json"],
    "filename": [".jshintrc", ".jsbeautifyrc"]
    //  "ext": ["js", "json"]
    // ^^ to set extensions to be beautified using the javascript beautifier
  },
  "css": ["css", "scss"],
  "html": ["htm", "html", "php", "blade"]
  // ^^ providing just an array sets the VS Code file type
}
```

But it's still not setting html styles within php. any advice?

Comment: I don’t see how some code formatting extension is related to syntax highlighting...?

Comment: The extension is the solution that was recommended in another post. Essentially, .php files that have html code, will not high-light the html code portions, only stuff within the php tags. beautify is supposed to apply HTML highlighting and php highlighting to the same file.